# PHP sum values from multidimensional array with using a for loop

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this..

```
$array = array (
    'section1' => array (
        'value'  => 465,
        'value2' => 744
    ),
    'section2' => array (
        'value'  => 6544,
        'value2' => 565
    ),
    'section5' => array (
        'value'  => 345,
        'value2' => 7465
    )
);
```

I want to add all of the `value2` together. I know I can do it with a for loop but is there a way to do it without doing this?

Could I use `array_sum` in combination with `array_column` to do this? The number of sections and the section name changes so I am not sure how to cater for this.

Comment: _Could I use array_sum in combination with array_column to do this?_ Yes

Comment: You can use array_reduce

Comment: `echo array_sum(array_column( $array, 'value2'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_walk for example and passing $sum by reference.

```
<?php
$array = array (
    'section1' => array (
        'value'  => 465,
        'value2' => 744
    ),
    'section2' => array (
        'value'  => 6544,
        'value2' => 565
    ),
    'section5' => array (
        'value'  => 345,
        'value2' => 7465
    )
);

$sum = 0;
array_walk($array, function($a) use (&$sum){
    $sum2 += $a['value2'];
});

print_r($sum);
// 8774
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_map`](https://www.tehplayground.com/sRkobEJytaC2QYkQ) to extract the required key's value, and then use `array_sum`.

```
$a = array (
    'section1' => array (
        'value'  => 465,
        'value2' => 744
    ),
    'section2' => array (
        'value'  => 6544,
        'value2' => 565
    ),
    'section5' => array (
        'value'  => 345,
        'value2' => 7465
    )
);

echo array_sum(array_map('v',$a));

function v($v) {return $v['value2'];}
```

[Teh Playground!](https://www.tehplayground.com/sRkobEJytaC2QYkQ)

Answer (score 2):

`array_reduce` variant:

```
$a = array (
    'section1' => array (
        'value'  => 465,
        'value2' => 744
    ),
    'section2' => array (
        'value'  => 6544,
        'value2' => 565
    ),
    'section5' => array (
        'value'  => 345,
        'value2' => 7465
    )
);

print_r($a);

echo array_reduce($a, function($c, $s) { return $c + $s['value2']; }, 0);

// shorter with arrow functions
echo array_reduce($a, fn($c, $s) => $c + $s['value2'], 0);
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/38LzLqt170VutBo6).

Answer (score 0):

I just used OOP to handle this

```
<?php
//Define class for calculating sum of value1 & value2
class _array {
    //Define variables
    private $sum_of_value = 0;
    private $sum_of_value_2 = 0;
    private $array = [];
    //Appending object in list
    public function append($title,$_value,$_value2)
    {
        $this->array[$title] = new obj($_value,$_value2);
        $this->sum_of_value = $this->sum_of_value + $_value;
        $this->sum_of_value_2 = $this->sum_of_value_2 + $_value2;
    }
    //Return list
    public function getArray()
    {
        var_dump($this->array);
    }
    //Return sum of value
    public function getSumOfValue()
    {
        echo $this->sum_of_value;
    }
    //Return sum of value2
    public function getSumOfValue2()
    {
        echo $this->sum_of_value_2;
    }

}
//Definiton of our object
class obj{
    public $value;
    public $value2;
    function __construct($value,$value2) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->value2 = $value2;
      }
}
//Enter values
$array = new _array();
$array->append('section1',465,744);
$array->append('section2',6544,565);
$array->append('section5',345,7465);
//Get array
$array->getArray();
//Get sum of value & sum of value 2
$array->getSumOfValue();
echo '<br>';
$array->getSumOfValue2();
?>
```